# this vector has vector probelem is not working

Tags: visual-c++

The problem is it prints the full name but not the rest of the lines about the person.
Could someone, please guide me?
I do really appreciate your help!

```
  auto itr = find(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), search );
   if(itr != my_vec.end()) 
   {  
    std::cout << "Match found " <<  search << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  "\nFull name:    " << search << std::endl;
       } else {
         std::cout << "Match not found "<< std::endl;
       }
```

Comment: If I gave you a list of lines, how would you, as a person, know when the record for a particular person ended and another one began?

Comment: As a new user, please read [tour], [ask], and [example]. This question has a lot of extra information that makes it harder to answer. Good questions take time to write, but they get answers much faster (or at all).

Comment: Well, I suppose, I would look for the lines of the list. To check if it is the start or the end. (=

Comment: Hey John! Thank you! I will read it! (=

Comment: Do the ends of the records really end with `<=== Line about the person ends here!`? If so, and if that's how you as a human would recognize the end of the record, then that's how you should make the computer do it.

Comment: I have changed The question now! Thank you for the observation! I must admit, It is difficult to ask the right question. (=

Comment: honestly I thought the question title was okay. There's a lot of info in the question body. I'm sure you could write a much smaller [example] that illustrates the same problem you're having in this large code example, but that's easier for an answerer to understand.

Comment: I also recommend consulting your teaching staff about how structs work. The fact that you don't have experience with that means you're not picking up fundamental concepts.

Comment: Hey John! You are right! I'm new to programming. All of this is new for me. Started two months ago, Challenged me to create a menu for users to (Add, Delete and search for person). I must say it has been really educational and fun at the same time (=

Comment: Sure, that's fine. I'm not making a value judgment. Everyone starts somewhere. There are a million subjects I'm less-than-a-beginner on. But for fundamental language concepts and how to use them practically, your best resource is the staff of competent experts that you are paying to teach you.

Comment: Thank you, John! I really appreciate your comments.  :D

Comment: Your edit also turned a compilable program (complicated as it was) into something that won't compile. [example] doesn't mean delete code so that it's smaller and doesn't compile. It means simplify and/or distill. I promise I'm not trying to make this difficult on purpose.

Comment: Not at all, I agree with you, John! Great observation! I'm happy you reply!

Comment: I hope it looks fine now! (=

Comment: I'm still open for feedback! (=

Comment: @JohnFilleau Can you please give me an example, I have been trying but still my code doesn't work! It still gives me back the first string about the person! (=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few style problems with your code:

1. No need to explicitly initialize strings, they will be empty by default (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)).
2. Keep a consistent style. For example, either always start brackets in the same line as the function signature or in the next line.
3. No need to close the file explicitly at the end of the function, this is done when the object goes out of scope (see `(destructor)` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)).
4. No need to include `<map>` and `<iomanip>` headers.
5. Don't keep unused variables.
6. Give suggestive names to your variables.
7. Do not return error codes to the OS when the app is working as it should. Not finding a name is not an error, is it?

It seems your file has 6 entries per contact, so all you have to do is print 5 more lines. You do not need to store the lines in a vector, just parse and print them as you go. Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

void findContact(std::string fullName, std::string contactListPath) {

    std::ifstream inFile{contactListPath};
    if (!inFile) {
        std::cerr << "File could not be open!" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inFile, line)) {
        if (line == fullName) {
            std::cout << "Match found: \n";
            std::cout << "\nFull name: " << fullName;
            std::cout << "\nAddress: " << (std::getline(inFile, line), line);
            std::cout << "\nE-mail: " << (std::getline(inFile, line), line);
            std::cout << "\nPhone: " << (std::getline(inFile, line), line);
            std::cout << "\nBirthday: " << (std::getline(inFile, line), line);
            std::cout << "\nNote: " << (std::getline(inFile, line), line) << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Match not found " << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    std::string fullName;
    std::string contactListPath;

    std::cout << "Enter full name to search: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, fullName);

    std::cout << "Enter path to contact list: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, contactListPath);

    findContact(fullName, contactListPath);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey MangaD! Thank you so much for your answer! I'm grateful from bottom of my heart!

Comment: How can I learn Programming like you?

Comment: Your code is efficient, however, It prints notes for the rest of the outputs except the full name! The full name is correct.

Comment: The Ide is to call the function through a header file. to the main.cpp (=

Comment: Full name: Tome Cruise

Comment: Full n Address: Mission Accomplished

Comment: E-mail: Mission Accomplished

Comment: Phone: Mission Accomplished Birthday

Comment: Note: Mission Accomplished ````

Comment: Make it work, Thank you so much again! (= I'm grateful

Comment: Made it work now with my program! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Justin Yes, sorry, I ignored the [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) problem. In my machine it was printing fine, but there are no guarantees about the order of operations and that is why it did not print well for you. The order of evaluation for the insertion operator (<<) may be undefined, but it is well defined for the comma operator. Edited my answer to fix this.

Comment: Thank you so much @MangaD  I appreciate everything.

Comment: What does this do (std::getline(inFile, line), line);

Comment: I know about getline(inFile, lien), however, the second line one is new for me!

Comment: @Justin That is the comma operator. The expressions are evaluated from left to right and the value of the rightmost expression is returned. So, this was the way I found to read a line from the file and return it in the same statement.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_comma_operator.htm

Comment: Can you please Give a beginner such as someone like me some advice on how to become a competent programmer like you?

Comment: @Justin I have been into CSE for 10 years now, and I still have much to learn myself. The advice I can give you is to study and practice. Read tutorials online, watch YouTube videos, be curious about everything. Start your own hobby projects. They will be clumsy at first but will allow you to learn from experience. Ask a senior to review your code. Do not be afraid to ask questions even for small things. Good luck. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your sincere answer! I will do so! Merry Christmas and happy holidays.  (=

Answer (score 2):

If every entry contains 6 lines. Then you can print all the lines starting from the line that you found like:

```
auto itr = find(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), search );
if(itr != my_vec.end()) 
{  
  std::cout << "Match found " << std::endl;
  // print the next 6 lines
  for(int remaining = 6;remaining > 0 && itr!=my_vec.end(); itr++,remaining--) {
    std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
  }
} else {
      std::cout << "Match not found "<< std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hey Peter! Thank you so much for your help!  I see what I did wrong!

Comment: I mean, I was missing! I didn't know this approach before! Can you please tell me how I can learn this kind of data manipulation?